Using Terraform's helm_release, how do I set a list of objects?
I need to override a list of objects in a helm values file (using the terraform helm_release resource)
For example, imagePullSecrets is often a list of YAML objects which could be overwritten.
    imagePullSecrets: 
      - name: artifactory-image-pull 

This gave me some hope, but it only describes how to override a simple list, not a list of objects: Using Terraform's helm_release, how do I set array or list values?
I tried this with no luck:
    set {
      name  = "imagePullSecrets[0].name"
      value = var.image_pull_secret_name
    }

I also tried to use set_list but this was mostly a stab in the dark:
    set_list {
      name  = "imagePullSecrets"
      value = [{ name : var.image_pull_secret_name }]
    }


I've done something similar when deploying the helm release for argocd. Here's an example:
locals {
  helm_extra_args = {
    "repoServer.image.repository"                = "..."
    "repoServer.image.tag"                       = "..."
    "repoServer.volumes[0].configMap.name"       = "..."
    "repoServer.volumes[0].name"                 = "..."
    "repoServer.volumes[1].name"                 = "..."
    "repoServer.volumes[1].secret.items[0].key"  = "..."
    "repoServer.volumes[1].secret.items[0].path" = "..."
    "repoServer.volumes[1].secret.secretName"    = "..."
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
  name       = "argocd"
  repository = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"
  chart      = "argo-cd"
  version    = "7.1.3"

  dynamic "set" {
    for_each = local.helm_extra_args
    content {
      name  = set.key
      value = set.value
    }
  }
}


Thank you, @Paolo.  It appears you are able to use the syntax I tried in my first example with name  = "imagePullSecrets[0].name".  I'll have to figure out why that is still not doing the override for me.

@JonCarlson Just make sure you use the helm_release resource the same way I am

Thanks @Paolo.  I like how you did that to avoid having 4 lines for each (of many) set commands.
I found another example in our codebase where using set with name = "imagePullSecrets[0].name" works like you used.  Not sure why it did not work for me but I ended up switching to the values = [...] option with values files to get things working.

You're welcome. Consider upvoting as well if you found the answer helpful.
